# Controlling property names when exporting to JSON in Rascal

Tags: json, rascal

I am writing some data to a file with `writeJSON` from the `lang::json::IO` module.

Example:

```
map[str, value] volumeMetrics = ();
map[str path, map[loc location, int lineCount] methods] = ...; // some data
volumeMetrics["files"] = methodLineCountPerFile;
```

How can I control the names of the properties in the resulting JSON without going through the hierarchy of objects and specifying them manually? In this particular case I would want the JSON objects to have properties named after the labels defined in the map (e.g. "path", "location", "linecount", "methods"). Instead, this data is now directly written as object properties.

(partial) sample output:

```
  "/src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionUCase.java": [
    [
      {
        "scheme": "java+compilationUnit",
        "authority": "",
        "path": "/src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionUCase.java",
        "offset": 1600,
        "length": 32,
        "begin": [
          47,
          41
        ],
        "end": [
          49,
          2
        ]
      },
      3
    ],
    [
      {
        "scheme": "java+compilationUnit",
        "authority": "",
        "path": "/src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionUCase.java",
        "offset": 1679,
        "length": 80,
        "begin": [
          52,
          41
        ],
        "end": [
          55,
          2
        ]
      },
      4
    ],
    [
      {
        "scheme": "java+compilationUnit",
        "authority": "",
        "path": "/src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionUCase.java",
        "offset": 1810,
        "length": 78,
        "begin": [
          58,
          43
        ],
        "end": [
          61,
          2
        ]
      },
      4
    ],
    [
      {
        "scheme": "java+compilationUnit",
        "authority": "",
        "path": "/src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionUCase.java",
        "offset": 1518,
        "length": 35,
        "begin": [
          42,
          25
        ],
        "end": [
          44,
          2
        ]
      },
      3
    ]
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data` constructors of Rascal to create nested structure, which can  then be mapped to JSON structure:

```
rascal>data Metric = path(int i);
ok
rascal>import lang::json::IO;
Loading module |lib://rascal/lang/json/IO.rsc|
ok
rascal>writeJSON(|home:///test.json|, path(20))
ok
rascal>import IO;
ok
rascal>println(readFile(|home:///test.json|))
{"path":{"i":20}}
ok
```

So you could create a `Metric` constructor for every kind of metric you have and work with that, or you can have a single constructor with different fields, like this:

```
rascal>data Metrics = metrics(int a, int b, int c);
ok
rascal>writeJSON(|home:///test.json|, metrics(1,2,3))
ok
rascal>println(readFile(|home:///test.json|))
{"metrics":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}}
ok
```

Here you use the labels of the fields of the constructors to name the metrics.

PS, the `unpackedLocations` keyword parameter to writeJSON is useful to make the source locations take up less space.

Comment: This works both ways, BTW. You could read back the JSON and reconstruct the Rascal `data` constructors.

Comment: The `util::WebServer` module does this automatically if you want to serve JSON content.

Comment: This works, but can I control property names easily in this setup? I have different types of metrics with different property names, but they are structurally the same, e.g.: `data Metric = complexity(num cyclomaticComplexity) | duplication(num duplicationPercentage) | volume(num projectLineCount);`. This feels clunky though.

Comment: I agree; the JSON / ADT fit is not perfect. I don't have a perfect solution, but there is an alternative that I will add to the answer.